# Handling errors within Django views

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form where all the fields are valid. I now want to send an email if the form is valid but if sending the email fails, I want to generate an error message for the user. What is the proper way to do this?
Should I redirect the user to a new page with the error or re-render the form as invalid.

#### views.py

```
from myapp.forms import ContactForm
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class ContactView(FormView):
    template_name = 'contact.html'
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = '/thanks/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
        # It should return an HttpResponse.
        form.send_email()
        return super(ContactView, self).form_valid(form)
```

In this example if `form.send_emai()` returns an error message, whats the best way to return that message back to the user? My `send_email()` function returns an error if the user has already sent the same email before, or if the recipient has opted out of receiving emails. I want to relay these messages back to the user.

Comment: If you do not want to show 500  page to user, use try & except to catch potential errors and use django messages framework to relay the information back to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add your checks to the form's `clean()` method? That way, you don't have to worry about returning error messages from `form.send_email()`.

Comment: It would be possible but I thought validation logic should only be in the clean()  method. Was hoping for a cleaner way

Comment: Both the examples you gave (checking whether the email has been sent before, checking whether a selected user has opted out) sound like validation issues to me.